# Помогите с библиотекой Speech Recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи

Обычная функция Speech Recognitition, которая выводит на экран то что вы сказали, но прежде чем она выведет что я сказал, мне надо будет примерно 3 секунды помолчать и только тогда программа поймёт что я уже ничего не говорю и выведет текст, и для моего проекта это совершенно не подходит.

Вопрос: Можно ли "завершить" прослушивание программой голоса вручную и убрать эту задержку тишины?

```
def command():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Говорите")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    zadanie = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
    print("Вы сказали: " + zadanie)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    talk("Я вас не поняла")
    zadanie = command()
return zadanie
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, дело не в молчании. Google speech recognize работает online. За эти 3 секунды возможно он посылает вашу аудиозапись на сервер, а потом она идёт с сервера к вам уже в виде текста. Задержка будет всегда. Если нужно, чтобы программа была без задержек, то нужно использовать оффлайн функции распознавания речи. Их много. **НО** Google speech recognize один из лучших и точных вариантов. Так что если будете использовать оффлайн распознавание, возможно уменьшится точность.